# Pattern for interdependent Properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property in my ViewModel which affects another property, for instance a SelectedDate and a ReferenceDate.

Whenever the SelectedDate changes the ReferenceDate is automatically set to a value lower than the SelectedDate, which of course requires that both values are updated in the ui. E.g.:

```
public SelectedDate
{
    set
    {
        _selectedDate = value;
        _referentialDate = value.AddDays(-1);
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDate");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ReferentialDate");
    }
}
```

This updated is handled with the property changed mechanism, which also takes care of loading related data. The same should also be possible for the ReferentialDate only:

```
public ReferentialDate
{
    set
    {
        _referentialDate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ReferentialDate");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this implementation leads to ReferentialDate being called twice when the SelectedDate changes. Is there some pattern or solution to prevent multiple calls to ReferentialDate?

Comment: If ReferentialDate is always 1 day before SelectedDate, then you could get rid of _referentialDate, and make a ReferentialDate getter that calculates the value from SelectedDate.

Comment: You should also be able to indenpendently select the ReferentialDate. So it's not always just 1 day before SelectedDate.

Comment: The relationship between SelectedDate and ReferentialDate is unclear - could you please explain?  For example, if SelectedDate is changed by 3 days (either towards the past or the future), should ReferentialDate change by 3 days to maintain the difference between the two dates?  Right now, your code does not do that.

Comment: Exactly if SelectedDate is changed by 3 days ReferentialDate is changed by 4 days. If ReferentialDate is changed on it's own, SelectedDate is not touched.

Comment: `Exactly if SelectedDate is changed by 3 days ReferentialDate is changed by 4 days.` - Are you sure you don't mean "Exactly if SelectedDate is changed by 3 days ReferentialDate is changed by **3** days."?  That way the interval between the dates remains the same?

Comment: Yes i meant the actual value. The difference stays the same.

Comment: Then I would model it by making the referential date a calculated value based on two properties: the selected date, and the interval between selected date and referential date.

When you modify the selected date, no other properties need to be modified.
When the caller modifies the referential date, a new date interval is stored, which changes the calculation of the referential date.

The referential date is not stored - it is calculated in the ReferentialDate getter.

Comment: Yes. Make normal property for the ReferentialDate if that doesn't get set from the UI. Else is fine

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem:

```
public SelectedDate
{
    set
    {
      _selectedDate = value;
      ReferentialDate = value.AddDays(-1);
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDate");          
    }
}
```